# Two series connected batteries of different voltage

Tags: batteries

On my electro motor Super Soco TC,
I have two batteries connected in parallel, both 60V and 30Ah.

The battery charger is at 71V. At 60V the BMS shuts down battery.

At full throttle on the bike, thr current goes up to 80A (40A each battery.)

Acceleration is great but I want little more of top speed so I need more voltage.

Can I connect a 60V-30Ah battery in series with 12V- 30Ah?

[image]

Comment: You can do that but you may fry your controller, It probably was not designed for 70+ volts.

Comment: Actually yes it is and that is good news :) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes in principle there’s no problem; each battery is a number of cells in series, so you’re effectively making a battery with more cells in series.  Ideally you would use identical cells, but should be ok if they are of similar capacity.  You’d need to consider how you’ll charge them, whether as two separate packs or as one, and in the latter case what happens if one pack reaches full charge before the other.

Answer (score 0):

2 or more batteries in series are commonly used everywhere.

Usually they connect in series batteries of the same type or the same chemistry.